# How to use Sony Xperia Z's burst mode programatically?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, camera, android-sdk, sony-xperia-z

I'm trying to trigger the Xperia Z camera in burst mode based on an event and I'm not sure what the best approach is.

So far I've tried this:

1. Installed [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) and setup a **Take Photo** Action but there isn't an option for the Burst Camera Mode and haven't found a way to toggle that on
2. Tried setting up the [Xperia Z AOSP project](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/device-sony-c6603) but ran into [issues](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/device-sony-c6603/issues/6)
3. Setup an Android test using the default [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class but even though I was able to take basic snapshots, the class does not expose a Burst Mode.

Any clues on how I can automate triggering the Xperia Z camera in burst mode ?

Comment: download Timeshift burst
Sony Mobile Communications

Comment: Can this application be controlled programatically ?